# Cannot change the display resolution size on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution, screen

Got a dual boot computer with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 20.04.
Decided to boot Linux for work and the resolution became unexpectedly low (1024x768).

Display resolution size:

[image: Display setting screenshot]

Apparently I have only one mode available to set the resolution and NVIDIA VGA compatible controller.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Tried to modify 2 files with:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/compiz
```

and with:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

but they are empty

xorg.conf:

[image: xorg.conf]

compiz:

[image: compiz]

The recommended NVIDIA driver is already installed

[image: Screenhot]

Installing another outputs an error.

[image: Another screenshot]

I have a monitor of 1440x900, and it's working OK on Windows.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and try again.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an NVIDIA driver controlling a NVIDIA display card then consider

```
sudo apt install nvidia-settings
```

I use this app to change my display card settings all the time. In my case, I have to use X11 as my display manager, because Wayland does not work with my display card.